# How to find the non-serializable value in the redux store?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I encounter the following warning from redux toolkit.

[image]
However the error is not specificying where the non-seralizable actually is in my state.

My raw state from the redux dev tools looks like this. The warning occurs immededtly after starting the application.

```
  user: {
    ids: [
      '61345318-2f7c-41ff-996c-4e537afcd5a1'
    ],
    entities: {
      '61345318-2f7c-41ff-996c-4e537afcd5a1': {
        sub: '61345318-2f7c-41ff-996c-4e537afcd5a1',
        email_verified: true,
        name: 'Daniel Hallosdfsdf',
        preferred_username: 'dani_1234',
        email: 'sdfdsfdsfsdf@foo.com'
      }
    },
    loggedInUser: '61345318-2f7c-41ff-996c-4e537afcd5a1',
    isAuthenticated: true,
    authenticationIsLoading: false,
    loginIsLoading: false,
    registerIsLoading: false,
    deleteAccountAWSIsLoading: false,
    resendSignUpLingIsLoading: false,
    fullNameChangingIsLoading: false,
    updateUsernameIsLoading: false,
    sendCodeForMailUpdateIsLoading: false,
    verifyEmailChangeCodeIsLoading: false,
    passwordChangingIsLoading: false,
    passwordForgottenMailIsSendLoading: false,
    passwordChangingAfterPasswordForgottenIsLoading: false,
    checkIfMailExistsIsLoading: false,
    checkIfUsernameExistsIsLoading: false,
    userSessionIsLoading: 'success',
    userIsLoading: 'sucess',
    getUpdatedSUYUHUserIsLoading: false,
    getUpdatedAWSUserIsLoading: false
  },
  story: {
    ids: [],
    entities: {},
    storyList: {
      isLoading: 'idle',
      count: '',
      numberOfStories: '',
      ids: []
    },
    storyListSideBarMap: {
      isLoading: 'idle',
      count: '',
      numberOfStories: '',
      ids: []
    },
    singleStory: {
      isLoading: 'idle',
      id: ''
    },
    updateStoryIsLoading: false,
    postStoryIsLoading: false
  },
  place: {
    ids: [],
    entities: {},
    placeList: {
      count: '',
      ids: []
    },
    placeSlider: {
      isLoading: 'idle',
      ids: []
    },
    placesOfStory: {
      isLoading: 'idle'
    },
    placeBar: {
      isLoading: 'idle',
      id: ''
    },
    placesOnMap: {
      isLoading: 'idle',
      ids: []
    },
    selectedPlaceId: ''
  },
  profile: {
    ids: [
      'dani_1234'
    ],
    entities: {
      dani_1234: {
        cognitoId: '61345318-2f7c-41ff-996c-4e537afcd5a1',
        username: 'dani_1234',
        bio: 'xcyvycxvxcvcxvcxv',
        shortTitle: 'MUCsdfsdfdsfdsfng',
        image: 'http://localhost:8000/media/profile_pics/Capture_1_5F75wR1.JPG',
        storiesUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/stories/?author=61345318-2f7c-41ff-996c-4e537afcd5a1',
        placesUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/places/?author=61345318-2f7c-41ff-996c-4e537afcd5a1',
        storiesCount: 1,
        placesCount: 1,
        profileOwnerPermission: true
      }
    },
    profileList: {
      isLoading: 'idle',
      count: '',
      ids: []
    },
    profileListSideBar: {
      isLoading: 'idle',
      count: '',
      ids: []
    },
    profileBar: {
      isLoading: true,
      id: ''
    },
    header: {
      isLoading: 'failure',
      id: 'dani_1234'
    },
    profilesOfStory: {
      isLoading: 'idle'
    },
    updateProfileImageIsLoading: false,
    updateDescriptionIsLoading: false,
    deleteProfileImageIsLoading: false,
    updateNicknameIsLoading: false
  },
  storyImage: {
    ids: [],
    entities: {},
    storyImageList: {
      isLoading: 'idle',
      ids: []
    },
    addStoryImageIsLoading: false,
    updateStoryImageIsLoading: false,
    deleteStoryImageIsLoading: false
  },
  userInterface: {
    ids: [],
    entities: {},
    profileEditIsOpen: false,
    stepProfileEdit: 'EditProfile',
    userAuthenticatesIsOpen: false,
    stepUserAuthenticates: 'signIn',
    browseMapOverlayIsOpen: false
  }
}
```

I am happy for any clarification that helps me to find the non serializable value.

Comment: Literally the next word after "in the path" where you cut off the error message should contain the exact identifying path of the non-serializable value.